# Beamer theme Antibes plus navigation bar with circles for subsections?

Tags: beamer, themes

I want to use the following Latex template (found [here](https://www.overleaf.com/5480233qdytzn#/17540204/)). However I want also to

(1) add a navigation bar with circles from Slide 3, at the top, next to the subsection title in the lilac part of the bar, highlighting the counting of each slide within the subsection.

(2) be able at each slide to go back to the outline slide with a single click.

Could you help me?

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}


\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}


\usetheme{Antibes}
%\usetheme{Madrid}
%\usecolortheme[named=Maroon]{structure}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\useinnertheme{circles}

\newtheorem*{bem}{Bemerkung}

\usepackage{tikz}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\lstset{frame=tb,
  language=Java,
  aboveskip=2mm,
  belowskip=2mm,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=flexible,
  basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
  numbers=none,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  tabsize=2
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\title[Knowledge graph in Neo4J]{Knowledge graph in Neo4J with SparQL Interface}
\author[DBPRO]{Asmaa Haja, Josseph Medina \\ Ilhem Bouzir \\ Supervisor: Dr. Holmer Hemsen}
\institute{TU Berlin}
%\logo{\includegraphics[height=0.5cm]{Bilder/TUBerlinLogo.png}}
\date{13.Juli.2015}
%\logo{\pgfimage[height=0.8cm]{Bilder/neo4j_logo.png}}
%\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[height=0.5cm]{Bilder/TUBerlinLogo.png} \includegraphics[height=0.6cm]{Bilder/dimalogo.png}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Inhaltsverzeichnis}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

    \section{Projekt}

        \subsection{Unseres Projekt}

        \begin{frame}{Unseres Projekt}
        Tourism in Deutschland\\
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Blah %Sehenswürdigkeiten
        \item Blah%Entfernung zwischen zwei Städte      
        \end{itemize}
        \end{frame}

        \subsection{Verwndete Tools}
        \begin{frame}{Verwndete Tools}
        %\includegraphics[height=2.cm]{Bilder/Java_logo.png}
        %\includegraphics[height=2.cm]{Bilder/neo4j_logo.png}
        %\includegraphics[height=2.cm]{Bilder/SPARQL.png}
        \end{frame}

    \section{Umsetzung}

        \subsection{1. Meilstein}

        \begin{frame}{1. Meilstein}
        Blah %Eingewönung an den Themen:
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Knowledge Graphen
        \item Neo4j
        \item Cypher
        \item Sparql
        \end{itemize}
        \end{frame}

        \subsection{2. Meilstein}

        \begin{frame}{2. Meilstein}
        Blah% Eingewönung an den Themen:
        \begin{itemize}
        \item DBpedia
        \item OWL, RDF,RDFS.
        \item Bkah %Anfragen an DBpedia über Sparql-Interface.
        \end{itemize}
        \end{frame}

        \subsection{3. Meilstein}

        \begin{frame}{3. Meilstein}
        Umsetzung der geplanten Ziele anhand von Tools:\\
        \begin{itemize}
        \item VBlah %Java Schnittstelle für den Nutzer
        \end{itemize}
        \begin{center}
        %\includegraphics[height=4.cm]{Bilder/GUI1.png}
        \end{center}
        \end{frame}

        %\Bild Anfrage Über Sparql Interface
        \begin{frame}{3. Meilstein}
        Umsetzung der geplanten Ziele anhand von Tools:\\
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Erstellung der Datenbank .
        \item Blah %Anfrage über Sparql Interface.
        \end{itemize}
        \begin{center}
       % \includegraphics[height=4.cm]{Bilder/PIC0.png}
        \end{center}    
        \end{frame}


        %\Bild Ergebniss Anfrage Über Sparql Interface
        \begin{frame}{3. Meilstein}
        Umsetzung der geplanten Ziele anhand von Tools:\\
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Erstellung der Datenbank. 
        \item Ergebniss der Anfrage.
        \end{itemize}
        \begin{center}
       % \includegraphics[height=4.cm]{Bilder/PIC0_1.png}
        \end{center}    
        \end{frame}

         %Bild Alle städte in deutschland
        \begin{frame}{3. Meilstein}
        Umsetzung der geplanten Ziele anhand von Tools:\\
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Erstellung der Datenbank.
        \end{itemize}
        \begin{center}
        %\includegraphics[height=4.cm]{Bilder/Neo4j2.png}
        \end{center}    
        \end{frame}

         %Bild GUI nach cklicken Auf start
        \begin{frame}{3. Meilstein}
        Umsetzung der geplanten Ziele anhand von Tools:\\
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Datenbak erstellt.
        \end{itemize}
        \begin{center}
       % \includegraphics[height=4.cm]{Bilder/GUI2.png}
        \end{center}    
        \end{frame}

        %\bild Berlin und ihre Sehenswürdichkeiten
        \begin{frame}{3. Meilstein}
        Umsetzung der geplanten Ziele anhand von Tools:\\
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Erstellung des Knowledgegraphs
        \end{itemize}
        \begin{center}
        %\includegraphics[height=4.cm]{Bilder/Neo4j2.png}
        \end{center}    
        \end{frame}

        %\subsection{3. Meilstein}
        \begin{frame}{3. Meilstein}
        Umsetzung der geplanten Ziele anhand von Tools.
        %\includegraphics[height=4.cm]{Bilder/Neo4j2.png}    
        \end{frame}


    \section{Neues}    
    \begin{frame}{Neues}
     \begin{itemize}
        \item Anpassen der GUI
        \end{itemize}

    \begin{center}
       % \includegraphics[height=4.cm]{Bilder/PIC5.png}
        \end{center}    


    \begin{itemize}
        \item Blah %Bilder zu der gewählten Sehenswürdigkeiten
        \end{itemize}

    \begin{center}
        %\includegraphics[height=4.cm]{Bilder/PIC6.png}
        \end{center}    
    \end{frame}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

This edit is realted to the answer below that does not work with the packages I use:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\usepackage{soul}
\newcommand{\hlc}[2][yellow]{ {\sethlcolor{#1} \hl{#2}} }


\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{bbm}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%\usepackage{pgf}
%\usepackage{etex}
%\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}


\usetheme{Antibes}
%\usetheme{Madrid}
%\usecolortheme[named=Maroon]{structure}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\useinnertheme{circles}

\newtheorem*{bem}{Bemerkung}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

%\useoutertheme[section=false]{smoothbars}


\newcommand{\beginbackup}{
   \newcounter{framenumbervorappendix}
   \setcounter{framenumbervorappendix}{\value{framenumber}}
}
\newcommand{\backupend}{
   \addtocounter{framenumbervorappendix}{-\value{framenumber}}
   \addtocounter{framenumber}{\value{framenumbervorappendix}} 
}





%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\lstset{frame=tb,
  language=Java,
  aboveskip=2mm,
  belowskip=2mm,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=flexible,
  basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
  numbers=none,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  tabsize=2
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\title[Paper]{Paper}
\date{\today}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}


\beginbackup
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
\backupend

\begin{frame}[label=toc]
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{BLAH}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\subsection{sub1}

\begin{frame}{SLIDE1}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want to count each frame or each slide per subsection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usetheme{Antibes}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\useinnertheme{circles}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcount\beamer@subsectionstartframe
\beamer@subsectionstartframe=1
\apptocmd{\beamer@subsection}{\addtocontents{nav}{\protect\headcommand{%
            \protect\beamer@subsectionframes{\the\beamer@subsectionstartframe}{\the\c@framenumber}}}}{}{}
\apptocmd{\beamer@subsection}{\beamer@subsectionstartframe=\c@framenumber\advance\beamer@subsectionstartframe by1\relax}{}{}
\AtEndDocument{\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\@writefile{nav}%
        {\noexpand\headcommand{\noexpand\beamer@subsectionframes{\the\beamer@subsectionstartframe}{\the\c@framenumber}}}}}{}{}
\def\beamer@startframeofsubsection{1}
\def\beamer@endframeofsubsection{1}
\def\beamer@subsectionframes#1#2{%
    \ifnum\c@framenumber<#1%
    \else%
    \ifnum\c@framenumber>#2%
    \else%
    \gdef\beamer@startframeofsubsection{#1}%
    \gdef\beamer@endframeofsubsection{#2}%
    \fi%
    \fi%
}
\newcommand\insertsubsectionstartframe{\beamer@startframeofsubsection}
\newcommand\insertsubsectionendframe{\beamer@endframeofsubsection}
\makeatother

\newcounter{subsectionframenumber}
\newcounter{totalsubsectionframenumber}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,right]{section in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\insertsectionhead\hspace*{2ex}
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,left]{subsection in head/foot}%
            \parbox[b]{.4\textwidth}{
            \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\hspace*{2ex}\insertsubsectionhead%
            \setcounter{subsectionframenumber}{1}
            \addtocounter{subsectionframenumber}{\insertframenumber}
            \addtocounter{subsectionframenumber}{-\insertsubsectionstartframe}
            \setcounter{totalsubsectionframenumber}{1}
            \addtocounter{totalsubsectionframenumber}{\insertsubsectionendframe}
            \addtocounter{totalsubsectionframenumber}{-\insertsubsectionstartframe}
            \ifnum\value{section}>0%
            \foreach\x in {1,...,\value{totalsubsectionframenumber}}{%
                \ifnum\x=\value{subsectionframenumber}%
                \usebeamertemplate{mini frame}~%
                \else%
                \usebeamertemplate{mini frame in other subsection}~%
                \fi%
            }%
            \fi%
        }%
        \hfill\hyperlink{toc}{ToC}%
        \end{beamercolorbox}}%
        \vskip0pt%
    }


\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}[label=toc]
        \tableofcontents
    \end{frame}

    \section{Section 1}
    \subsection{Subsection 1}
    \frame{\frametitle{Frame 1}}
    \frame{\frametitle{Frame 2}}
    \frame{\frametitle{Frame 3}}
    \subsection{Subsection 2}
    \frame{\frametitle{Frame 1}}
    \frame{\frametitle{Frame 2}}
    \frame{\frametitle{Frame 3}}
    \frame{\frametitle{Frame 4}}
    \section{Section 2}
    \subsection{Subsection 1}
    \frame{\frametitle{Frame 1}}
    \frame{\frametitle{Frame 2}}
    \frame{\frametitle{Frame 3}}
    \subsection{Subsection 2}
    \frame{\frametitle{Frame 1}}
    \frame{\frametitle{Frame 2}}
    \frame{\frametitle{Frame 3}}
    \frame{\frametitle{Frame 4}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Tried with your updated example, and I don't get any problems

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\usepackage{soul}
\newcommand{\hlc}[2][yellow]{ {\sethlcolor{#1} \hl{#2}} }


\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{bbm}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%\usepackage{pgf}
%\usepackage{etex}
%\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}


\usetheme{Antibes}
%\usetheme{Madrid}
%\usecolortheme[named=Maroon]{structure}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\useinnertheme{circles}

\newtheorem*{bem}{Bemerkung}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

%\useoutertheme[section=false]{smoothbars}


\newcommand{\beginbackup}{
    \newcounter{framenumbervorappendix}
    \setcounter{framenumbervorappendix}{\value{framenumber}}
}
\newcommand{\backupend}{
    \addtocounter{framenumbervorappendix}{-\value{framenumber}}
    \addtocounter{framenumber}{\value{framenumbervorappendix}} 
}





%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\lstset{frame=tb,
    language=Java,
    aboveskip=2mm,
    belowskip=2mm,
    showstringspaces=false,
    columns=flexible,
    basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
    numbers=none,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
    stringstyle=\color{mauve},
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    tabsize=2
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\title[Paper]{Paper}
\date{\today}

\makeatletter
\newcount\beamer@subsectionstartframe
\beamer@subsectionstartframe=1
\apptocmd{\beamer@subsection}{\addtocontents{nav}{\protect\headcommand{%
            \protect\beamer@subsectionframes{\the\beamer@subsectionstartframe}{\the\c@framenumber}}}}{}{}
\apptocmd{\beamer@subsection}{\beamer@subsectionstartframe=\c@framenumber\advance\beamer@subsectionstartframe by1\relax}{}{}
\AtEndDocument{\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\@writefile{nav}%
        {\noexpand\headcommand{\noexpand\beamer@subsectionframes{\the\beamer@subsectionstartframe}{\the\c@framenumber}}}}}{}{}
\def\beamer@startframeofsubsection{1}
\def\beamer@endframeofsubsection{1}
\def\beamer@subsectionframes#1#2{%
    \ifnum\c@framenumber<#1%
    \else%
    \ifnum\c@framenumber>#2%
    \else%
    \gdef\beamer@startframeofsubsection{#1}%
    \gdef\beamer@endframeofsubsection{#2}%
    \fi%
    \fi%
}
\newcommand\insertsubsectionstartframe{\beamer@startframeofsubsection}
\newcommand\insertsubsectionendframe{\beamer@endframeofsubsection}
\makeatother

\newcounter{subsectionframenumber}
\newcounter{totalsubsectionframenumber}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,right]{section in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\insertsectionhead\hspace*{2ex}
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,left]{subsection in head/foot}%
            \parbox[b]{.4\textwidth}{
                \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\hspace*{2ex}\insertsubsectionhead%
                \setcounter{subsectionframenumber}{1}
                \addtocounter{subsectionframenumber}{\insertframenumber}
                \addtocounter{subsectionframenumber}{-\insertsubsectionstartframe}
                \setcounter{totalsubsectionframenumber}{1}
                \addtocounter{totalsubsectionframenumber}{\insertsubsectionendframe}
                \addtocounter{totalsubsectionframenumber}{-\insertsubsectionstartframe}
                \ifnum\value{section}>0%
                \foreach\x in {1,...,\value{totalsubsectionframenumber}}{%
                    \ifnum\x=\thesubsectionframenumber%
                    \usebeamertemplate{mini frame}~%
                    \else%
                    \usebeamertemplate{mini frame in other subsection}~%
                    \fi%
                }%
                \fi%
            }%
            \hfill\hyperlink{toc}{ToC}%
        \end{beamercolorbox}}%
        \vskip0pt%
    }


\begin{document}


    \beginbackup
    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}
    \backupend

    \begin{frame}[label=toc]
        \frametitle{Outline}
        \tableofcontents
    \end{frame}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \section{BLAH}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \subsection{sub1}

    \begin{frame}{SLIDE1}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{SLIDE2}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Also with really many (O(100)) frames per subsection, I don't get any problems, besides that it looks ugly:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it looks good in your example, but when I run it using my slides it gives me a lot of issues. It seems that after a certain number of slides plus if I have backup slides it gives errors. I have added in my questions the packages I use

Comment: @user3285148 I tried with your updated example and do not get any errors, see the edit in my answer. What errors do you get? Have you tried to delete all the auxiliary files and compile from clean again?