# Custom frame: automatic frametitle and framesubtitle with miniframes-like bullets?

Tags: beamer, mini-frames

I'm trying to define my own minimal `frametitle` style. I'm close to want I want, but I struggle to get automatic `miniframes`-like bullets.

See the MWE for more information.

Is there any simple way to use the built-in bullet navigation in `beamer` `miniframes` to obtain what I want?

(Also feel free to criticise the way I did things, as it is probably not it should be done!)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{textcomp} % for \textopenbullet

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=black!20}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
{
   \nointerlineskip
   \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.0cm,ht=10mm,wd=\paperwidth]{frametitle}
      \vbox{}\vskip-0ex%
      \strut%
      \hspace*{4mm}\insertframetitle%
      \hfill{\scriptsize\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}\hspace*{0.5cm}%
      \ifx\insertframesubtitle
         \newline\hspace*{4mm}\small\strut\phantom{Pq}%
      \else
         \newline\hspace*{4mm}\small\strut\insertframesubtitle%
      \fi
   \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{
   \let\insertframetitle\insertsectionhead}{}
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{
   \let\insertframesubtitle\insertsubsectionhead}{}

\makeatletter
  \CheckCommand*\beamer@checkframetitle{\@ifnextchar\bgroup\beamer@inlineframetitle{}}
  \renewcommand*\beamer@checkframetitle{\global\let\beamer@frametitle\relax\@ifnextchar\bgroup\beamer@inlineframetitle{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\part{Part1}    
\section{Sec1}

\begin{frame}
   I would like to automatize the `navigation bullets' in the frametitle and in the framesubtitle. Here that would give:\\[5mm]
   Sec1 (\textbullet\textopenbullet\textopenbullet\textopenbullet\textopenbullet)
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
   I would like to automatize the `navigation bullets' in the frametitle and in the framesubtitle. Here that would give:\\[5mm]
   Sec1 (\textbullet\textbullet\textopenbullet\textopenbullet\textopenbullet)
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsec1.1}

\begin{frame}
   I would like to automatize the `navigation bullets' in the frametitle and in the framesubtitle. Here that would give:\\[5mm]
   Sec1 (\textbullet\textbullet\textbullet\textopenbullet\textopenbullet)\\
   Subsec1.1 (\textbullet\textopenbullet)
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
   I would like to automatize the `navigation bullets' in the frametitle and in the framesubtitle. Here that would give:\\[5mm]
   Sec1 (\textbullet\textbullet\textbullet\textbullet\textopenbullet)\\
   Subsec1.1 (\textbullet\textbullet)
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsec1.2}

\begin{frame}
   I would like to automatize the `navigation bullets' in the frametitle and in the framesubtitle. Here that would give:\\[5mm]
   Sec1 (\textbullet\textbullet\textbullet\textbullet\textbullet)\\
   Subsec1.1\\[5mm]
   Note that when there is only one frame in section or subsection, no bullets should be shown. 
\end{frame}

\section{Sec2}
\subsection{Subsec2.1}

\begin{frame}
   I would like to automatize the `navigation bullets' in the frametitle and in the framesubtitle. Here that would give:\\[5mm]
   Sec2 (\textbullet\textopenbullet\textopenbullet)\\
   Subsec2.1\\[5mm]
   Note that when there is only one frame in section or subsection, no bullets should be shown.    
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsec2.2}

\begin{frame}
   I would like to automatize the `navigation bullets' in the frametitle and in the framesubtitle. Here that would give:\\[5mm]
   Sec2 (\textbullet\textbullet\textopenbullet)\\
   Subsec2.1 (\textbullet\textopenbullet)\\[1cm]
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
   I would like to automatize the `navigation bullets' in the frametitle and in the framesubtitle. Here that would give:\\[5mm]
   Sec2 (\textbullet\textbullet\textbullet)\\
   Subsec2.1 (\textbullet\textbullet)\\[1cm]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

## =================

EDIT: getting real close to want I want, thanks to samcarter comment! But there are still a few things to iron out (see the new MWE).

New MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{textcomp} % for \textopenbullet

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=black!20}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcount\beamer@subsectionstartframe
\beamer@subsectionstartframe=1
\apptocmd{\beamer@subsection}{\addtocontents{nav}{\protect\headcommand{%
            \protect\beamer@subsectionframes{\the\beamer@subsectionstartframe}{\the\c@framenumber}}}}{}{}
\apptocmd{\beamer@subsection}{\beamer@subsectionstartframe=\c@framenumber\advance\beamer@subsectionstartframe by1\relax}{}{}
\AtEndDocument{\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\@writefile{nav}%
        {\noexpand\headcommand{\noexpand\beamer@subsectionframes{\the\beamer@subsectionstartframe}{\the\c@framenumber}}}}}{}{}
\def\beamer@startframeofsubsection{1}
\def\beamer@endframeofsubsection{1}
\def\beamer@subsectionframes#1#2{%
    \ifnum\c@framenumber<#1%
    \else%
    \ifnum\c@framenumber>#2%
    \else%
    \gdef\beamer@startframeofsubsection{#1}%
    \gdef\beamer@endframeofsubsection{#2}%
    \fi%
    \fi%
}
\newcommand\insertsubsectionstartframe{\beamer@startframeofsubsection}
\newcommand\insertsubsectionendframe{\beamer@endframeofsubsection}

\newcount\beamer@sectionstartframe
\beamer@sectionstartframe=1
\apptocmd{\beamer@section}{\addtocontents{nav}{\protect\headcommand{%
            \protect\beamer@sectionframes{\the\beamer@sectionstartframe}{\the\c@framenumber}}}}{}{}
\apptocmd{\beamer@section}{\beamer@sectionstartframe=\c@framenumber\advance\beamer@sectionstartframe by1\relax}{}{}
\AtEndDocument{\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\@writefile{nav}%
        {\noexpand\headcommand{\noexpand\beamer@sectionframes{\the\beamer@sectionstartframe}{\the\c@framenumber}}}}}{}{}
\def\beamer@startframeofsection{1}
\def\beamer@endframeofsection{1}
\def\beamer@sectionframes#1#2{%
    \ifnum\c@framenumber<#1%
    \else%
    \ifnum\c@framenumber>#2%
    \else%
    \gdef\beamer@startframeofsection{#1}%
    \gdef\beamer@endframeofsection{#2}%
    \fi%
    \fi%
}
\newcommand\insertsectionstartframe{\beamer@startframeofsection}
\newcommand\insertsectionendframe{\beamer@endframeofsection}
\makeatother

\newcounter{subsectionframenumber}
\newcounter{totalsubsectionframenumber}
\newcounter{sectionframenumber}
\newcounter{totalsectionframenumber}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
{
   \nointerlineskip
   \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.0cm,ht=10mm,wd=\paperwidth]{frametitle}
      \vbox{}\vskip-0ex%
      \strut%
      \hspace*{4mm}\insertframetitle\ (%
      \setcounter{sectionframenumber}{1}%
      \addtocounter{sectionframenumber}{\insertframenumber}%
      \addtocounter{sectionframenumber}{-\insertsectionstartframe}%
      \setcounter{totalsectionframenumber}{1}%
      \addtocounter{totalsectionframenumber}{\insertsectionendframe}%
      \addtocounter{totalsectionframenumber}{-\insertsectionstartframe}%
      \ifnum\value{section}>0%
      \foreach\x in {1,...,\value{totalsectionframenumber}}{%
          \ifnum \x<\numexpr\value{sectionframenumber}+1%
          \textbullet%
          \else%
          \textopenbullet%
          \fi%
      }%
      \fi%
      )%
      \hfill{\scriptsize\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}\hspace*{0.5cm}%
      \ifx\insertframesubtitle
         \newline\hspace*{4mm}\small\strut\phantom{Pq}%
      \else
         \newline\hspace*{4mm}\small\strut\insertframesubtitle\ (%
         \setcounter{subsectionframenumber}{1}%
         \addtocounter{subsectionframenumber}{\insertframenumber}%
         \addtocounter{subsectionframenumber}{-\insertsubsectionstartframe}%
         \setcounter{totalsubsectionframenumber}{1}%
         \addtocounter{totalsubsectionframenumber}{\insertsubsectionendframe}%
         \addtocounter{totalsubsectionframenumber}{-\insertsubsectionstartframe}%
         \ifnum\value{section}>0%
         \foreach\x in {1,...,\value{totalsubsectionframenumber}}{%
             \ifnum\x<\numexpr\value{subsectionframenumber}+1%
             \textbullet%
             \else%
             \textopenbullet%
             \fi%
         }%
         \fi%
      \fi%
      )%
   \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{
   \let\insertframetitle\insertsectionhead}{}
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{
   \let\insertframesubtitle\insertsubsectionhead}{}

\makeatletter
  \CheckCommand*\beamer@checkframetitle{\@ifnextchar\bgroup\beamer@inlineframetitle{}}
  \renewcommand*\beamer@checkframetitle{\global\let\beamer@frametitle\relax\@ifnextchar\bgroup\beamer@inlineframetitle{}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\part{Part1}

\section{Sec1}

\begin{frame}
   I would like to automatize the `navigation bullets' in the frametitle and in the framesubtitle. Here that would give:\\[5mm]
   Sec1 (\textbullet\textopenbullet\textopenbullet\textopenbullet\textopenbullet)\\[5mm]

   \color{red}Note that when there is no subsection, no bullets should be shown.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
   I would like to automatize the `navigation bullets' in the frametitle and in the framesubtitle. Here that would give:\\[5mm]
   Sec1 (\textbullet\textbullet\textopenbullet\textopenbullet\textopenbullet)\\[5mm]

   \color{red}Note that when there is no subsection, no bullets should be shown.
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsec1.1}

\begin{frame}
   I would like to automatize the `navigation bullets' in the frametitle and in the framesubtitle. Here that would give:\\[5mm]
   Sec1 (\textbullet\textbullet\textbullet\textopenbullet\textopenbullet)\\
   Subsec1.1 (\textbullet\textopenbullet)
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
   I would like to automatize the `navigation bullets' in the frametitle and in the framesubtitle. Here that would give:\\[5mm]
   Sec1 (\textbullet\textbullet\textbullet\textbullet\textopenbullet)\\
   Subsec1.1 (\textbullet\textbullet)
\end{frame}


\subsection{Subsec1.2}

\begin{frame}
   I would like to automatize the `navigation bullets' in the frametitle and in the framesubtitle. Here that would give:\\[5mm]
   Sec1 (\textbullet\textbullet\textbullet\textbullet\textbullet)\\
   Subsec1.2\\[5mm]
   \color{red}Note that when there is only one frame in section or subsection, no bullets should be shown.
\end{frame}

\section{Sec2}

\subsection{Subsec2.1}

\begin{frame}
   I would like to automatize the `navigation bullets' in the frametitle and in the framesubtitle. Here that would give:\\[5mm]
   Sec2 (\textbullet\textopenbullet\textopenbullet)\\
   Subsec2.1\\[5mm]
   \color{red}Note that when there is only one frame in section or subsection, no bullets should be shown.
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsec2.2}

\begin{frame}
   I would like to automatize the `navigation bullets' in the frametitle and in the framesubtitle. Here that would give:\\[5mm]
   Sec2 (\textbullet\textbullet\textopenbullet)\\
   Subsec2.2 (\textbullet\textopenbullet)\\[5mm]

   \color{red}I don't know why there is 3 bullets in the subsection here.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
   I would like to automatize the `navigation bullets' in the frametitle and in the framesubtitle. Here that would give:\\[5mm]
   Sec2 (\textbullet\textbullet\textbullet)\\
   Subsec2.2 (\textbullet\textbullet)\\[5mm]

   \color{red}I don't know why there is 3 bullets in the subsection here.
\end{frame}

\section{Sec3}

\begin{frame}
   I would like to automatize the `navigation bullets' in the frametitle and in the framesubtitle. Here that would give:\\[5mm]
   Sec3\\[5mm]

   \color{red}I don't know why there is 3 bullets in the subsection here.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can manually insert miniframes, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/332018/36296 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/313579/36296 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/314961/36296

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I edited my question as I still have some issues (highlighted in the MWE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **when there is no subsection, no bullets should be shown**: You can test if you are outside of a subsubsection with `\ifnum\thesubsection=0`
- **when there is only one frame in section or subsection, no bullets should be shown**: If there is only one frame in the (sub)section, then the start end frame is the same. This can be tested by `\ifnum\insertsubsectionstartframe=\insertsubsectionendframe` and `\ifnum\insertsectionstartframe=\insertsectionendframe`
- **why there are 3 bullets in the subsection**: I think this boils down to the fact that the section end is not recognised as as subsection end as well. As a workaround this situation can be caught by testing `\ifnum\insertsubsectionendframe<\insertsectionendframe`

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{textcomp} % for \textopenbullet

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=black!20}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
%\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcount\beamer@subsectionstartframe
\beamer@subsectionstartframe=1

\apptocmd{\beamer@subsection}{\addtocontents{nav}{\protect\headcommand{%
            \protect\beamer@subsectionframes{\the\beamer@subsectionstartframe}{\the\c@framenumber}}}}{}{}          

\apptocmd{\beamer@subsection}{\beamer@subsectionstartframe=\c@framenumber\advance\beamer@subsectionstartframe by1\relax}{}{}

\AtEndDocument{\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\@writefile{nav}%
        {\noexpand\headcommand{\noexpand\beamer@subsectionframes{\the\beamer@subsectionstartframe}{\the\c@framenumber}}}}}{}{}
\def\beamer@startframeofsubsection{1}
\def\beamer@endframeofsubsection{1}
\def\beamer@subsectionframes#1#2{%
    \ifnum\c@framenumber<#1%
    \else%
    \ifnum\c@framenumber>#2%
    \else%
    \gdef\beamer@startframeofsubsection{#1}%
    \gdef\beamer@endframeofsubsection{#2}%
    \fi%
    \fi%
}
\newcommand\insertsubsectionstartframe{\beamer@startframeofsubsection}
\newcommand\insertsubsectionendframe{\beamer@endframeofsubsection}

\newcount\beamer@sectionstartframe
\beamer@sectionstartframe=1
\apptocmd{\beamer@section}{\addtocontents{nav}{\protect\headcommand{%
            \protect\beamer@sectionframes{\the\beamer@sectionstartframe}{\the\c@framenumber}}}}{}{}
\apptocmd{\beamer@section}{\beamer@sectionstartframe=\c@framenumber\advance\beamer@sectionstartframe by1\relax}{}{}
\AtEndDocument{\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\@writefile{nav}%
        {\noexpand\headcommand{\noexpand\beamer@sectionframes{\the\beamer@sectionstartframe}{\the\c@framenumber}}}}}{}{}
\def\beamer@startframeofsection{1}
\def\beamer@endframeofsection{1}
\def\beamer@sectionframes#1#2{%
    \ifnum\c@framenumber<#1%
    \else%
    \ifnum\c@framenumber>#2%
    \else%
    \gdef\beamer@startframeofsection{#1}%
    \gdef\beamer@endframeofsection{#2}%
    \fi%
    \fi%
}
\newcommand\insertsectionstartframe{\beamer@startframeofsection}
\newcommand\insertsectionendframe{\beamer@endframeofsection}
\makeatother

\newcounter{subsectionframenumber}
\newcounter{totalsubsectionframenumber}
\newcounter{sectionframenumber}
\newcounter{totalsectionframenumber}
\newcounter{stopframe}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
{
   \nointerlineskip
   \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.0cm,ht=10mm,wd=\paperwidth]{frametitle}
      \vbox{}\vskip-0ex%
      \strut%
      \hspace*{4mm}\insertsectionhead%
      \ifnum\insertsectionstartframe=\insertsectionendframe%
      \else%
      \space(%
      \setcounter{sectionframenumber}{1}%
      \addtocounter{sectionframenumber}{\insertframenumber}%
      \addtocounter{sectionframenumber}{-\insertsectionstartframe}%
      \setcounter{totalsectionframenumber}{1}%
      \addtocounter{totalsectionframenumber}{\insertsectionendframe}%
      \addtocounter{totalsectionframenumber}{-\insertsectionstartframe}%
      \ifnum\value{section}>0%
      \foreach\x in {1,...,\value{totalsectionframenumber}}{%
          \ifnum \x<\numexpr\value{sectionframenumber}+1%
          \textbullet%
          \else%
          \textopenbullet%
          \fi%
      }%
      \fi%
      )%
      \fi%
      \hfill{\scriptsize\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}\hspace*{0.5cm}%
      \ifnum\thesubsection=0
         \newline\hspace*{4mm}\small\strut\phantom{Pq}%
      \else
             \newline\hspace*{4mm}\small\strut\insertsubsectionhead%
             \ifnum\insertsubsectionstartframe=\insertsubsectionendframe%
             \else%
             \space(%
             \setcounter{subsectionframenumber}{1}%
             \addtocounter{subsectionframenumber}{\insertframenumber}%
             \addtocounter{subsectionframenumber}{-\insertsubsectionstartframe}%
             \setcounter{totalsubsectionframenumber}{1}%
             \ifnum\insertsubsectionendframe<\insertsectionendframe
                \addtocounter{totalsubsectionframenumber}{\insertsubsectionendframe}%
             \else%
                   \addtocounter{totalsubsectionframenumber}{\insertsectionendframe}%
             \fi%
             \addtocounter{totalsubsectionframenumber}{-\insertsubsectionstartframe}%
             \ifnum\value{section}>0%
             \foreach\x in {1,...,\value{totalsubsectionframenumber}}{%
                 \ifnum\x<\numexpr\value{subsectionframenumber}+1%
                 \textbullet%
                 \else%
                 \textopenbullet%
                 \fi%
             }%
             \fi%
             )%
           \fi%  
      \fi%
   \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\makeatletter
  \CheckCommand*\beamer@checkframetitle{\@ifnextchar\bgroup\beamer@inlineframetitle{}}
  \renewcommand*\beamer@checkframetitle{\global\let\beamer@frametitle\relax\@ifnextchar\bgroup\beamer@inlineframetitle{}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\part{Part1}

\section{Sec1}

\begin{frame}
   I would like to automatize the `navigation bullets' in the frametitle and in the framesubtitle. Here that would give:\\[5mm]
   Sec1 (\textbullet\textopenbullet\textopenbullet\textopenbullet\textopenbullet)\\[5mm]

   \color{red}Note that when there is no subsection, no bullets should be shown.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
   I would like to automatize the `navigation bullets' in the frametitle and in the framesubtitle. Here that would give:\\[5mm]
   Sec1 (\textbullet\textbullet\textopenbullet\textopenbullet\textopenbullet)\\[5mm]

   \color{red}Note that when there is no subsection, no bullets should be shown.
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsec1.1}

\begin{frame}
   I would like to automatize the `navigation bullets' in the frametitle and in the framesubtitle. Here that would give:\\[5mm]
   Sec1 (\textbullet\textbullet\textbullet\textopenbullet\textopenbullet)\\
   Subsec1.1 (\textbullet\textopenbullet)
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
   I would like to automatize the `navigation bullets' in the frametitle and in the framesubtitle. Here that would give:\\[5mm]
   Sec1 (\textbullet\textbullet\textbullet\textbullet\textopenbullet)\\
   Subsec1.1 (\textbullet\textbullet)
\end{frame}


\subsection{Subsec1.2}

\begin{frame}
   I would like to automatize the `navigation bullets' in the frametitle and in the framesubtitle. Here that would give:\\[5mm]
   Sec1 (\textbullet\textbullet\textbullet\textbullet\textbullet)\\
   Subsec1.2\\[5mm]
   \color{red}Note that when there is only one frame in section or subsection, no bullets should be shown.
\end{frame}

\section{Sec2}

\subsection{Subsec2.1}

\begin{frame}
   I would like to automatize the `navigation bullets' in the frametitle and in the framesubtitle. Here that would give:\\[5mm]
   Sec2 (\textbullet\textopenbullet\textopenbullet)\\
   Subsec2.1\\[5mm]
   \color{red}Note that when there is only one frame in section or subsection, no bullets should be shown.
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsec2.2}

\begin{frame}
   I would like to automatize the `navigation bullets' in the frametitle and in the framesubtitle. Here that would give:\\[5mm]
   Sec2 (\textbullet\textbullet\textopenbullet)\\
   Subsec2.2 (\textbullet\textopenbullet)\\[5mm]

   \color{red}I don't know why there is 3 bullets in the subsection here.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
   I would like to automatize the `navigation bullets' in the frametitle and in the framesubtitle. Here that would give:\\[5mm]
   Sec2 (\textbullet\textbullet\textbullet)\\
   Subsec2.2 (\textbullet\textbullet)\\[5mm]

   \color{red}I don't know why there is 3 bullets in the subsection here.
\end{frame}

\section{Sec3}

\begin{frame}
   I would like to automatize the `navigation bullets' in the frametitle and in the framesubtitle. Here that would give:\\[5mm]
   Sec3\\[5mm]

   \color{red}I don't know why there is 3 bullets in the subsection here.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I learned a lot from this. Awesome!

Comment: @Bibi You're welcome! And thanks for preparing such a nice MWE to start with. Having the desired output on each slide to compare was a huge help!